# Treat URL path as virtual host using Apache

Tags: url, apache2, virtualhost

The problem is that I have only one domain name on which three different products need to be run (two of them PHP based and one python). So I need to treat the path in the URL as a different virtual host; i.e.:

```
www.domain.com/first_URL/
www.domain.com/second_URL/
www.domain.com/third_URL/
```

Where the first to third will act as separate virtual hosts.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something with the apache-config directives, since you're asking for a virtualhost solution. Apache can only work with virtualHosts as actual domains, as [cweiske explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896128/treat-url-path-as-virtual-host-using-apache/6896247#6896247).

The solution in this case would be to either use a `.htaccess` file in the sub-directories you're working in, or to set up a `<Directory "/web/root/subdir">..</Directory>` block within your current (virtual-)host configuration.

You could also choose to host them on different sub-domains if you per se want to run them as VirtualHosts ('app1.domain.org').

Comment: Well the problem is that I have only 1 domain with no possibility to add any more subdomains. And I need to run 3 different apps on it. The directory directive is not kinda an option since I can not place WSGI init scrpits in it.

Comment: @Ruslan: Without any experience from WSGI, a quickscan of the docs indicate that you can `WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/app1.wsgi` followed by `WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/app2.wsgi`, etc.. Not sure if that's enough?

Comment: In the regular virtual host config? (Not the directory-block one as suggested above). The scriptAlias can be called multiple times for different paths.

Comment: sorry that was my bad - made a typo

Answer (score 26):

This can be achieved by using the Alias or AliasMatch directive:

```
Alias /first_url/ /var/www/first_url_resources
```

More details can be found in *[Apache Module mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)*.

Comment: Old answer and even older question, I know, but this was exactly the type of single-line solution I was after. It's not easy to search for something when you're not sure of the syntax or context of what you're looking for. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing to note: the `Alias /url /path/to/dir` directive can be followed by a `<Directory /path/to/dir/>` directive to allow overrides for that specific directory.

Comment: This does not anser the question, because the `Alias` directive does not create a virtual host. So all directives, which can only be used in a virtual host (`SuexecUserGroup` for example), can not be used with this `Alias` workaround.

Answer (score 4):

A "virtual host" in Apache works on domain names only, not on parts of the path. You cannot achieve what you want.

Comment: Most people consider a virtual host setup similar to a reverse proxy in terms of end-user functionality. The question could be interpreted that way. Apache can do reverse proxy.

Answer (score 4):

This example explains how to assign a different PHP version per directory. It can also be adapted to add Python support by running the Python interpreter as `fast_cgi` on a particular port.

For the purpose of the example, I assume there is a separate directory for each PHP version and they are named according to the PHP version that runs them, but this can be adjusted.

```
mkdir /home/user/www
mkdir /home/user/www/5.6.5
mkdir /home/user/www/7.0.2
mkdir /home/user/www/7.0.4
mkdir /home/user/www/7.0.6
```

Create symbolic links to directories that should be handled by different PHP versions:

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/www/7.0.2/ /var/www/html/7.0.2
sudo ln -s /home/user/www/7.0.4/ /var/www/html/7.0.4
sudo ln -s /home/user/www/7.0.6/ /var/www/html/7.0.6
```

Then add the following lines to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf in default virtual host `*:80`

(For your needs, you can set up one more [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) handler here for the website that requires Python). I assume PHP 5.6.5 runs on port 9999, `7.0.2` runs on port `9998`, etc.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
ProxyPassMatch ^/5.6.5/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9999/var/www/html/
ProxyPassMatch ^/7.0.2/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9998/var/www/html/
ProxyPassMatch ^/7.0.4/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9997/var/www/html/
ProxyPassMatch ^/7.0.6/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9996/var/www/html/
```

Assuming your server is pointed by `example.com`, you can test it on:

```
http://example.com/5.6.5/
http://example.com/7.0.2/
http://example.com/7.0.4/
http://example.com/7.0.6/
```

Comment: this example seems needlessly complex.